# Excel function to find the last three items by date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am looking to obtain the 3 most recent transactions in relation to the date.  (The problem is that they are in the spreadsheet out of order,
and I don't want to do a sort.)

```
  Date       Amount
13/06/2015     15
01/06/2015     56
07/05/2015     33
04/06/2015     14
08/06/2015     22
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Dates are in column A and Amounts are in column B:

- Populate C2 with `=INDEX(B$2:B$6,MATCH(LARGE(A$2:A$6,ROWS(C$2:C2)),A$2:A$6,0))` and drag the fill
  handle down to C4.

[image]

Notice: I changed the date formatting.

Comment: Thank you for this, Is there anyway of combining the two formulas as I have lots of different amount colums (these are deliveries of different products) happening at different dates and I only want a consolidated view of how much was delivered for each in the latest 3 deliveries

Comment: @tads consider writing a macro or some .NET code.

Comment: Formulas combined, hope this helps.

Comment: Thinking about this a little further it occurs to me that their are two cases, which may not apply to this specific example, but may be useful to someone searching for a similar solution. One case would be scheduled deliveries that have yet to be made and should not be counted and the other is blank spaces. This formula `=INDEX(B$2:B$10,MATCH(LARGE(--(A$2:A$10<TODAY())*A$2:A$10,ROWS(C$2:C2)),A$2:A$10,0))` handles both. The formula needs to be entered by concurrently pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with `vlookup` if you know where your data is

Say your data begins on `A2` -

```
=VLOOKUP(LARGE($A$2:$A$10,Row()),$A$2:$B$10,2,0)
```

That formula will return the largest if it is put in D1 or any cell on Row 1. As you drag it down to Row 2, it will pick the 2nd largest. Etc..

If you need to put your formula in say cell E5 for the largest, just adjust -

```
=VLOOKUP(LARGE($A$2:$A$10,Row()-4),$A$2:$B$10,2,0)
```

Or of course, hard code it to something like -

```
=VLOOKUP(LARGE($A$2:$A$10,Row(A1)),$A$2:$B$10,2,0)
```